# Incrementing a combination of nvarchar and numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

following scenario: 
I need to increment a code like this one `DS0000001`
So next Item would be `DS0000002`, following `DS0000003` and so on.

So for generating this code in a big INSERT Statement I wrote the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.eufn_e5_importCRM_getNextClientCode(
  @partnerCode AS NVARCHAR(10),
  @number AS INT
    )
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(20)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @next AS INT
        DECLARE @zeroes AS NVARCHAR(10)
        DECLARE @nextStr AS NVARCHAR(10)
        DECLARE @return AS NVARCHAR(20)
        DECLARE @partnerPrefix AS NVARCHAR(10)

        SELECT @next = RIGHT(c.clientCode,7) FROM Clients c

        SELECT @partnerPrefix = partners.partnerPrefix
          FROM partners WHERE partnerCode = @partnerCode
        SET @next = ISNULL(@next,0) + @number   
        SET @nextStr = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),@next)

        SELECT @zeroes = CASE WHEN @next > 9 THEN '00000'
                WHEN @next > 99 THEN  '0000'
                WHEN @next > 999 THEN  '000'
                WHEN @next > 9999 THEN  '00'
                WHEN @next > 99999 THEN  '0'
                WHEN @next > 999999 THEN  ''
                ELSE '000000'
        END

        IF ISNULL(@next,'') = ''
        BEGIN
            SET @return = @partnerPrefix + @zeroes + '1'
        END
        ELSE SET @return = @partnerPrefix + @zeroes + @nextStr

        RETURN @return
    END
```

`@number` gets the row number I added in the insert statement manually with the `ROW_NUMBER()`-function.

This already works fine - it inserts the right code into the table.

What I don't like about the code is this part here:

```
SELECT @zeroes = CASE WHEN @next > 9 THEN '00000'
        WHEN @next > 99 THEN  '0000'
        WHEN @next > 999 THEN  '000'
        WHEN @next > 9999 THEN  '00'
        WHEN @next > 99999 THEN  '0'
        WHEN @next > 999999 THEN  ''
        ELSE '000000'
END
```

I already searched a while on stackoverflow and also googled, but I could not find a function like convert that leaves the "0" standing where they are.

Any ideas how to make this function more flexible and if possible: reusable?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe you are right. Slightly different scenario though. Seeing the solution it sounds similar, but in your link the answer (and most answers) did use other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an you can do it like this

```
Declare @a int
Set @a =8756
Select 'DS' + REPLACE(STR(@a, 7), SPACE(1), '0')
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8

Comment: Your sqlfiddle link seems broken.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo, Yes working on it, even I am not familiar with SQL Fiddle. It working now